# My code is not responding as i want it to be?

Tags: php, html

My php is not responding correctly here is my HTML code

```
 <html>
<body>
<form name="myform" method="post" action="lol.php">
<input type="text" name="man" value=""> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value= "post">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my PHP code

```
<?php 

if ($_POST['man']= null )
{print ('has no value');}
else {print ($_POST['man']);
}
?>
```

Comment: How is it responding?

Comment: How do you want it to respond?

Comment: it is not giving the if and else answers

Comment: $_POST["man"] == null not =

Comment: Looks like a case of `=` versus `==` to me.

Comment: if there is a text in man text box i should get the value of it in my php file but if there is null then it should say it has no value

Comment: This question is off-topic because it seems to be about fixing a basic syntax error.

Answer (score 7):

use `==` operator for comparison instead of `=` because the second one is for assignment.

```
if ($_POST['man']== null )
{
print ('has no value');}
else {
print ($_POST['man']);
}
```

See [PHP Comparison Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
if ($_POST['man']= null )
```

to

```
if ($_POST['man'] == null )
```

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving any error?

Try:

```
if (isset($_POST['man'])) {
  echo $_POST['man'];
}
else {
  echo 'Nothing';
}
```

And to confirm everything is working use this:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

The you will see the values on `$_POST`

Answer (score 0):

At First, you should use isset instead of =, second and very important: = is an assignment, but what you want is an comparison, so use == and compare against an empty string